# Set End datepicker Minimum date is More than Start Datepicker selected date in android not Working

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I want to show the **End mimimum Date value** is not Less  than selected Date in **Start Date value**

But in my code is showing **end date Min value** is from today's date.

help me ,How to solve it.

// for date picker show

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog.
            // set date picker for current date
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener1, Startyear, Startmonth, Startday);

        case DATE_PICKER_ID1:

            // open datepicker dialog.
            // set date picker for current date
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            //return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener2, Startyear, Startmonth, Startday);


       // set minimum date of end datepicker

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener2, Startyear, Startmonth, Startday);


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Startyear1new, Startmonth1new, Startday1new);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis()-10000);
        return dialog;


    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        Startyear = selectedYear;
        Startmonth = selectedMonth;
        Startday = selectedDay;



        // Show selected date
        StringBuilder dateValue=new StringBuilder().append(Startday).append("-")
                .append(Startmonth + 1).append("-").append(Startyear).append(" ");

        //for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
        SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String abs1= dateValue.toString();
        Date testDate1 = null;
        try {
            testDate1 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String DateFormat=formatter1.format(testDate1);
        CampStartDateEdittext_datepicker.setText(DateFormat);


    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay)
    {

        Endyear = selectedYear;
        Endmonth = selectedMonth;
        Endday = selectedDay;


        // Show selected date
        StringBuilder dateValue=new StringBuilder().append(Endday).append("-")
                .append(Endmonth + 1).append("-").append(Endyear).append(" ");


        //for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
        SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String abs1= dateValue.toString();
        Date testDate23 = null;
        try {
            testDate23 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String DateFormat=formatter1.format(testDate23);

        Camp_EndDateEdittext_datepicker.setText(DateFormat);


    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting validation for end date picker min value to be more than your start date picker value

```
mEndDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mEndDateTimeCal != null) {
                    mNowEndCal = mEndDateTimeCal;
                } else {
                    mNowEndCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                }

                DatePickerDialog dialog;
                if (mStartDay != null && mStartMonth != null && mStartYear != null) {
                    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(FOBookTripActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            mEndYear = year;
                            mEndMonth = monthOfYear;
                            mEndDay = dayOfMonth;
                            if (mEndDateTimeCal == null) {
                                mEndDateTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            }
                            mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mStartYear);
                            mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mStartMonth);
                            mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mStartDay);

                            mEndDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                            mEndDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                            mEndDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                            try {
                                if (mEndDateTimeCal != null && mEndDateTimeCal.before(mStartDateTimeCal)) {
                                    mEndDateTimeCal = mStartDateTimeCal;
                                    mEndDateButton.setText(CustomUtils.timeStampToHumanReadableDate(mEndDateTimeCal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000));
                                }
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();\
                            }
                        }
                    }, mStartYear, mStartMonth, mStartDay);

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(mStartYear, mStartMonth, mStartDay);

                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
                } 
                dialog.show();
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mNowStartCal.getTimeInMillis());

            }
        });
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i want to show the date selected  in start datepicker as minimum date in End Datepicker. without any validation.

Comment: In that case, within your onDateSelected for startDate picker you can set the minimum date for your endDate Picker. I hope you got it or you want me to provide you snippet.

Comment: I have added the another answer with the complete snippet. Kindly vote me if I have solved your query.

Comment: this code is showing from january 1900 not my selcted date

Comment: I guess you didn't see my other answer. That's the solution to your question. I am using the same logic and it's working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104999/discussion-between-kumar-and-mayank-bhatnagar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            DatePicker startDatePickerDialog startDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerstartDatePickerDialog(FOBookTripActivity.this, new DatePickerstartDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mStartDay = dayOfMonth;
                    mStartMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mStartYear = year;
                    if (mStartDateTimeCal == null) {
                        mStartDateTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    }
                    mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    mStartDateTimeCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    try {
                        mStartDateButton.setText(CustomUtils.timeStampToHumanReadableDate(mStartDateTimeCal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000));


                        //setting the start date selected as minimum date for End Date Picker Dialog
                        endDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mStartDateTimeCal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, mNowStartCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), mNowStartCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), mNowStartCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            startDatePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

On date select of 1st datePicker , initialize second one with that selected date.